# "Order by" results of "Group By" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure

```
leads
-----
id name

1   Varun
2   Vishal

visitors
--------
id name
1   Rahul
2   Akhshay

assigned_visitors
-----------------
av_id lead_id, visitor_id, visit_date
1   1       1           2020-11-28
2   1       2           2020-12-02
```

No I need to show the following result-set

```
leads.name   visitors.name    visit_date    
Varun        Akhshay          2020-12-02
```

The following SQL would show correct visit_date but not correct visitor name.

```
select l.*
     , l.Name as LeadName
     , l.Phone as LeadPhone
     , u.*
     , u.Name as VisitorName
     , u.Phone as VisitorPhone
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT visit_date ORDER BY av_id DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1) as max_visit_date 
  from leads as l 
  join assigned_visitors a 
    on l.id = a.lead_id 
  join users u 
    on u.user_id = a.visitor_id 
 where l.Status = 3 
 group 
    by l.id 
 HAVING (date(max_visit_date) BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') 
 order 
    by max_visit_date DESC
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, but also consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: And see about sql injection and the vital importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: ORDER BY AVId - I don't see avid anywhere else..

Comment: P.Salmon, I have updated. av_id is primary key of assigned-visitors table.

Comment: How is the one row in the result set determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is much more complicated than the data you show.  If I assume that you want the most recent visit for each lead, then one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*, av.*, u.*
from leads l join
     assigned_visitors av
     on l.id = av.lead_id join
     users u 
     on u.user_id = av.visitor_id 
where l.Status = 3 and
      av.visit_date = (select max(av2.visit_date)
                       from assigned_visitors av2
                       where av2.lead_id = av.lead_id
                      );
```

Aggregation would not be a valid approach to such a query.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But one change I had to.make, visit date can be changed higher to lower. So can't do max(visit_date). I had to update with max(av_id). Thanks again!